# Add new mandatory aspect to locked node

Tags: javascript, alfresco

**Situation**

1. A node was locked.
2. A change to the model introduced **a new mandatory aspect** (`cm:taggable`) which the locked node does not have.

**Problem**

It is **not possible to unlock** the node using the JavaScript console.

```
var node = search.findNode(nodeRefString);
node.unlock();
```

This throws an error:

```
org.alfresco.repo.node.integrity.IntegrityException: 03280783 Found 1 integrity violations:
Mandatory aspect not set: 
   Node: workspace://SpacesStore/84e053a2-4573-4542-ac17-0e6940b9b07c
   Type: {http://acme.com/model/acme/1.0}AcmeType
   Aspect: {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}taggable
```

It is also **not possible to add the missing aspect**. This

```
node.addAspect("cm:taggable");
```

throws a `NodeLockedException`. Deleting the Node

```
node.remove();
```

is also not possible.

**Question**

How can I solve this Catch 22?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [fme JavaScript console](http://alfresco.fme.de/extension-gallery/overview/javascript-console/), I've found a way to solve the problem. It is possible to **disable behaviours** on a node, include the behaviour that checks for the node being locked.

Inside the JavaScript console, this code does what I want:

```
var node = search.findNode(nodeRef);
var ctx = Packages.org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
var pbf = ctx.getBean("policyBehaviourFilter");
pbf.disableBehaviour(nodeRef);
node.addAspect("cm:taggable");
pbf.enableBehaviour(nodeRef);
```

Now the still locked node has the mandatory aspect. It now can be unlocked without any integrity problem.